# Can I install Godot Engine using Command Line?

Tags: software-installation, ppa

How can I install Godot Engine using command line? Is there a PPA for Godot Engine? I am waiting for the command to install it like `sudo apt-get install godot-engine`.

Comment: Does this http://cialu.net/blog/install-godot-engine-fedora-ubuntu.html  *how to install godot on ubuntu help* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the answer you want...

There are [stirrings on Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~jose-falanga-5/godot/master) but no PPA or anything looking useable at the moment.

I tried [downloading the compiled binary](https://godotengine.org/download) but it segfaulted immediately when I ran it :|

So I downloaded [this release (click to download)](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/archive/2.1.2-stable.tar.gz) from the [Godot Engine GitHub page](https://github.com/godotengine/godot) and followed [the instructions here](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/reference/compiling_for_x11.html) for compiling on Ubuntu.

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential scons pkg-config libx11-dev libxcursor-dev \
libxinerama-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu-dev libasound2-dev libpulse-dev \ 
libfreetype6-dev libssl-dev libudev-dev libxrandr-dev
```

Untar the source and enter the directory:

```
cd Downloads      # or wherever you put it
tar xf godot*
cd godot*
```

Now run:

```
scons platform=x11
```

*Many* CPU cycles later it compiled. The binary can be found in the `bin` directory in the top level directory of the source. It runs fine for me. You can symlink it to a location in your PATH for easier running, or make a launcher.

I'm on 16.10 (Ubuntu MATE). YMMV.

Answer (score 8):

Answer adapted from here: https://cialu.net/install-godot-game-engine-on-fedora-or-ubuntu/

First, download the appropriate version for your system (32 bit or 64 bit) from the [Godot Download Page](https://godotengine.org/download).

Open a Terminal window and enter:

`unzip Godot_v2.1-stable_x11.64.zip`

After, move the executable to /opt folder:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/Godot/

sudo mv Godot_v2.1-stable_x11.64 /opt/Godot/Godot
```

And make it executable:

`sudo chmod +x /opt/Godot/Godot`

Then, create and edit a launcher for Godot executable:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications/

nano godot.desktop
```

Populate the .desktop file, writing this in nano, saving with CTRL-O and exiting with CTRL-X:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Godot Engine

GenericName=Libre game engine
Comment=Multi-platform 2D and 3D game engine with a feature rich editor
Exec=/opt/Godot/Godot -pm
Icon=godot
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

And now you can launch Godot from your desktop system. If you want to customize the icon, just put the Godot icon in your theme and name it `godot`.

Comment: To customize the icon: Copy the `icon.png` from a new project generated by Godot into `~/.local/share/icons/godot.png`, and change the .desktop file to say `Icon=godot.png`.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way of installing software(If it's available):

```
sudo snap install godot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from FlatHub via Flatpak

```
https://flathub.org/apps/org.godotengine.Godot
```

or maybe from Snap store

```
https://snapcraft.io/godot-4
```